# Recent Posts widget missing current_menu_item class

Tags: menus, widgets

Unlike the (WP standard) Custom Menu widget, the Recent Posts widget does not add the current_menu_item class when a post is selected (being displayed).

This seems like a major oversight, am I missing something? If not, does anyone know of a third party widget that lists the most recent posts and includes the current_menu_item class (or equivalent)? ...or perhaps some magical hack to achieve the result of adding a class to the active menu item?

Answer (score 2):

The core Recent Posts Widget does not output any classes for the current post - probably because the Widget semantically is a *list* of posts, rather than a *navigation menu*, and therefore has no intended purpose to reflect current location.

That said, with a bit of CSS/jQuery trickery, you could target the current post by matching the current post's permalink and/or ID to the href and/or title attribute of the Recent Posts Widget list item link.

While the implementation itself is probably outside the scope of WPSE, the [relevant code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L510) is here:

```
<?php  while ($r->have_posts()) : $r->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title() ? get_the_title() : get_the_ID()); ?>"><?php if ( get_the_title() ) the_title(); else the_ID(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Use jQuery to match e.g. `.widget li a[href=<?php get_permalink(); ?>]`, or something along those lines.